# Transmission Transfer Duty Solenoid Hack; TCU Dummy Load Heat Management & Relay Debouncing

Tags: capacitor, resistors, relay, heat, debouncing

**Rev A**

I have tried to properly incorporate the things you outlined in the comments Tony. Honestly a lot of what you said went over my head and required some additional reading before I could respond. Thank you for your patience.

[image]

First, I must confess, I am an electrical engineering idiot. Ohm's law was something I had barely even heard spoken of until two days ago. I would very much welcome any feedback and criticism I can use constructively!

**Goals**

1: Cut power to the transfer duty solenoid in my car's transmission at the push of a button.

2: Create a 10-17ohm dummy load that generates as little heat as possible with passive cooling.

3: Premptively resolve possible issues with relay bounce.

**Desired Result**

The normally closed state of the 8 pin relay keeps the transmission control unit(TCU) connected to the transfer duty solenoid allowing the vehicle to control the state of the center differential. The normally open state of the 8 pin relay disconnects the TCU from the transfer duty solenoid and connects it to a dummy load preventing the vehicle from thinking the solenoid has failed resulting in an error code. Cutting off the solenoid from the TCU/power causes the transmission to enter a 50/50 front and rear power distribution. Essentially a locked center differential for those familiar with 4x4 and all wheel drive systems.

Comment: Why do you need to create a dummy load for sensing?  Current sensing done by TCU?  Use metal resistors clamped to chassis to be cool.  Not a reliability issue.

Comment: If the TCU senses a resistance outside of the 10-17ohm range it will trigger an error code and a check engine light. The dummy load is just to make the TCU think it is still looking at the solenoid. The preferred location of resistors would be in the cab under the dash to minimize risk of exposure to moisture during water crossings.

Comment: Higher power resistors don't reduce heat; they reduce temperature. The heat power or energy is the same.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification!

Comment: Maybe a better faster Relay would work.  Which one did you use?

Comment: Schneider Electric 8 pin model no. 782XBXM4L-12D

Answer (score 0):

### Rev A

The Below circuit won't work in any scenario with a bulk cap in any position. The RC =T2 is too small compare to the L/R ratio=T2  and i would resonate and cause close surge currents.

The real problem is the relay deadtime.  A FET Half Bridge is the best solution with delay. But if a passive solution is needed, a higher current coil ought to switch faster.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fPIFbD.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

This is a SWAG assuming I can mind-read your schematic.  Add a Cap between Throws to support the voltage transfer.

The big 1mF e-cap added gives RC = T = 17 ms which may or may not be enough to satisfy a debounce time. This assumes the TCU does solenoid current sensing to detect a fault and it uses a high side control.

A reverse diode is added assuming you forgot to add flyback EMI prevention.

Comment: Thank you for that, I have been looking at Circuitlab. So many of the symbols are unfamiliar I am still in the process of learning to use it. Your diagram sped that up immensely. I will post a diagram of where I am at currently ASAP. I truly appreciate the time that went into your response.

Comment: I guess yours differs by being low side current switching. The solution would be the same to put the cap across the “throws” of the SPDT switch in the correct polarity.

Comment: https://ibb.co/HTZNzsS - Sorry I can't figure out how to get it to display the image in the comment. The 100ohm resistor that the solenoid gets connected to as it is de-powered was suggested to me but the conversation was cut short before he could explain why.

Comment: The 100 ought to shunt the solenoid when opened and get 12V when selected in order to dissipate the flyback power.

Comment: Normally the R5 is directly across the coil with a series  reversed power diode so it switches faster than the transfer of the 2nd pole to reduce EMI spikes.  Cathode (bar) goes towards 12V.